# My link in webview doesn't open?

Tags: android, webview

How can i use this link "192.168.1.11:8080/..../login.html" in webView it's local web server.Am tried many times but nothing happened. my code is working with other link such as "google" , so please if any one could help..

this is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
    webView = (android.webkit.WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    startWebView("http://192.168.1.11:8080/...../login.html");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To use **loadUrl** instead of startWebView

```
  webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.11:8080/...../login.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your phones's network address are same as your local server.Then you can visit your server with your app on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check, if your phone is in your WLAN network and the mobile network is disabled.